# Mac - The framework 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '3.1.0' (x64) was not found

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am using a Mac (x64, Intel) and trying to test a Dotnet project.

I currently have 6.0.104 dotnet SDK installed, and when I am trying to test that project, I am facing the following error:

```
Testhost process exited with error: It was not possible to find any compatible framework version
The framework 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '3.1.0' (x64) was not found.
  - The following frameworks were found:
      6.0.4 at [/usr/local/Cellar/dotnet/6.0.104_1/libexec/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
You can resolve the problem by installing the specified framework and/or SDK.
The specified framework can be found at:
  - https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-applaunch?framework=Microsoft.NETCore.App&framework_version=3.1.0&arch=x64&rid=osx.12-x64
. Please check the diagnostic logs for more information.

Test Run Aborted.
```

I have installed 3.1.x SDK from this [page](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/thank-you/runtime-3.1.27-macos-x64-installer) and somehow it is not getting reflected. Is there a way we can bypass this error and change the SDK version?

Answer (score 2):

According to the error message ,it need the 3.1.0 runtime to run the asp.net core application, so I suggest you could try to go to this [page](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/3.1) to download  the 3.1.0 runtime to test again.

[image]

Another workaround is update your application to use dotnet core 3.1.24 instead of using the 3.1.0. It is too old which is out of support time.

Comment: I installed this version, but somehow it is not getting reflected, whenever I run `dotnet --version` it always says - 6.0.4